# Can I prevent an ng-model update with an asyncValidator?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I have an application where certain options do not play nicely together.  In the case where a user has chosen a pair of options that may lead to poor performance, we show a [dialog](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdDialog) where the user has to agree to acknowledge that they're asking for *a lot* of data and we may not be able to satisfy the request.

Since the dialog service returns a promise that can be fulfilled or rejected depending on what the user wants to do, This seems like a pretty great place to add an async validator on the [NgModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController).  I've written up a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ooJWwZfoHQSQTCYj9dJr?p=preview) to demonstrate the scenario and my attempt at a solution.

The guts of it are:

#### Html

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as ctrl">
  <br>
  Allow chili
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="ctrl.allowChili">
  <br>
  <select
      ng-model="ctrl.val"
      ng-model-options="{allowInvalid: false}"
      validate-async="ctrl.validateAsync($modelVal)"
      ng-change="ctrl.tellMe()">
    <option value="very">very</option>
    <option value="chili">chili</option>
    <option value="jalepeno">jalepeno</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <p>The food is {{ctrl.val}} spicy!</p>
</body>
```

#### JS

```
var myApp = angular.module('plunker', []);

myApp.controller('MainCtrl', ['$q', '$scope', function($q, $scope) {
    this.val = 'very';
    this.allowChili = false;

    this.validateAsync = function(modelVal) {
      console.log(modelVal);
      if (modelVal != 'chili' || this.allowChili) {
        console.log('Accepting validation');
        return $q.when();
      } else {
        console.log('Rejecting validation');
        return $q.reject();
      }
    };

    this.tellMe = function() {
      // In my application, this actually issues an HTTP request to get new
      // data and update the view.
      alert('model value changed');
    };
}]);

myApp.directive('validateAsync', ['$q', function($q) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: linkFn,
  };
  function linkFn(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
    ngModelCtrl.$asyncValidators.myValidator = function(modelVal, viewVal) {
      var args = {
        '$modelVal': modelVal,
        '$viewVal': viewVal,
      };
      return $q.when(scope.$eval(attrs['validateAsync'], args));
    };
  }
}]);
```

Unfortunately, there are a few problems.  When a the async validator promise is rejected two bad things happen:

1. Change listeners (e.g. `ng-change`) still fire and my view still gets updated.
2. The new model value appears to be `undefined` whereas I'd like to prevent it from changing at all.

How can an `NgModelController` prevent a staged change from being committed based on the status of a promise?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [plunker of an ugly hack](https://plnkr.co/edit/wDpM4KLAqyusrtpHWWY2) that I think I can adapt to my use-case.  The guts of the changes are in the `validateAsync` directive:

```
myApp.directive('validateAsync', ['$q', function($q) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: linkFn,
  };
  function linkFn(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
    var ngModelCtrl$setViewValue = ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue;
    ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue = function(value, trigger) {
      var args = {
        '$val': value,
        '$trigger': trigger,
      };
      $q.when(scope.$eval(attrs['validateAsync'], args)).then(function() {
        ngModelCtrl$setViewValue.call(ngModelCtrl, value, trigger);
      });
    };
  }
}]);
```

(with appropriate template changes to use `$val` rather than `$modelVal`).

Basically, I'm hijacking `NgModelController.$setViewValue` and not calling the base implementation if the promise is rejected.  In the demo plunker, you'll see that the `select` element still changes.  I believe that's OK with my designers (and if it isn't, I have the power to fix it in my use-case since I'm not actually using `<select>` elements -- I'm using a custom directive for picking the values that I have full control over when it updates).